# Json deserialization - expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, android, json, json-deserialization

This is the json I receive:

```
{
    "data": "{\"keystring\": \"ag5zfmNvcGFya3NlcnZlcnIUCxIHQ29tbWVudBiAgICAusaBCgw\"}",
    "isSucceed": true,
    "error": ""
}
```

And this is the class and the code which is supposed to de-serialize it:

```
public class ServerResponse {

    private boolean isSucceed;
    private String error;
    private JSONObject data;
}

//this is the code line responsible for deserialization, responseJson = the JSON above
ServerResponse response = gson.fromJson(responseJson, ServerResponse.class);
```

For some reason I get JsonSyntaxException: expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING, which I guess is related to the data object ServerResponse holds, but I recieve it as a valid Json...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` field

```
private JSONObject data;
```

is of type `JSONObject`. But the value you receive for the corresponding key-value pair

```
"data": "{\"keystring\": \"ag5zfmNvcGFya3NlcnZlcnIUCxIHQ29tbWVudBiAgICAusaBCgw\"}",
```

is a JSON string. A JSON string is meant to map to a Java `String`. So it expected a JSON object, but received a JSON String.

You can write and register your own `TypeAdapter` to make the conversion from JSON string to Java `JSONObject`. Or you can change your field to be of type `String` and convert it to a `JSONObject` when you need it.

Comment: How would I write my own TypeAdapter?

Comment: @Jjang It's a Gson class. [Here's an example.](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/)

Comment: TypeAdapter is definitely the way to go on this.